# Why WPF Application Requires Administrative Rights for every run?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, administrator, rights

I have a WPF Application. I have bundled it in a Setup.msi using WIXToolset.
The installer, by default, takes

''' C:\Program Files(x86)'''

path.

I understand that for running this .msi and installing the application, it requires Administrative Rights.

What I don't understand that is , after successful installation, Application calls for Administrator Rights for every run.

What could be wrong in the application ?... How can I make it not ask for Admin Rights for every run?

P S: This is on a Enterprise Secured PC. Also, My application Reads/Writes a log file in the same path of its exe. (Hope this is not the cause)

Comment: Does your Wix-Install-configuration contain the property "MSIUSEREALADMINDETECTION" and <![CDATA[Privileged]]>?

Comment: @true_gler Though I was not sure where to check this exactly as my Wix know-how is very beginner level, I did search all the files in Wix Project and nothing of this sort found.

Comment: "*My application Reads/Writes a log file in the same path of its exe.*" - this may well cause trouble. The installation path may not be writeable. `C:\Program Files(x86)` is not writeable for a standard user.

Comment: MS made it easy for you to know that's not the correct location to store your data-including log files-by requiring Administrative privileges to write to that location.

Comment: @Clemens If that's the reason , What's the correct way to write a log file? What path should be used on a Enterprise Secured PC?... How would application know which is writeable path?... And first of all, how does OS knows application would be writing a file even before it runs , such that it prompts for Admin Rights UAC?

Comment: Write to `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)` or a similar path.